# edit chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have been looking for a guide for how to add another sidebar to the sources tab.

I know we can download the devtools_frontend from the chromuim project and edit that, but I am wondering if anyone know if it's possible with an extension

I found a bunch for adding things to the elements but nothing for sources.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Chrome provides three separate APIs for extending the developer tool - http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/devtools.html
and more risky - http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/experimental.html

This is your way to add new tabs/features to the devtools.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to add to the Source panel a an extra sidebar. Those API's mostly work with adding additional tabs and sidebars to elements. - or at least I couldn't find any example of adding a tab to the source panel.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is years after your question, but you might want to check out [jQuery Audit](https://github.com/zertosh/jquery-audit) plugin on GitHub. It adds a tab/sidebar to the Sources panel/tab.